# dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library while doing dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc using dh-virtualenv

Tags: package-management, dpkg, debian

I am trying to build a debian package out of a python package using dh-virtualenv. I am doing this on a Mac, so I'm using Docker to do so.
The biggest problem is that package is dependent on PyQt5, and I'm getting some errors.

Here's the Dockerfile I'm using:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password ""' | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password ""' | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3.6 python3-pip debhelper python3-all dh-virtualenv \
    mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev python3-venv python3-venv \
    python3-pyqt5 qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Here's my setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import common

setup(
    name='myName',
    version=common.__version__,
    author='myAuthor',
    author_email='myAuthorEmail',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={'': ['etc/*']},
    include_package_data=True,
    url='myGitURL',
    description="myDescription",
    scripts=["myScript"],
    install_requires=[
        "alembic",
        "awscli",
        "boto3",
        "colorlog",
        "colorama",
        "docopt",
        "hypothesis",
        "matplotlib",
        "mock",
        "more_itertools",
        "mysqlclient",
        "netifaces",
        "numpy",
        "PyInstaller",
        "pyserial",
        "pytest",
        "pytest-cov",
        "pytest-mock",
        "PyYAML",
        "SQLAlchemy",
        "validators",
        "voluptuous",
        "filelock",
        "PyQt5",
        "fuzzywuzzy[speedup]",
        "wadlipac==1.0.12"  # Library from an internal PyPi server
    ],
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6'
    ]
)
```

Here's my debian control file:

```
Source: MYSOURCE
Section: python
Priority: extra
Maintainer: MYMAINTAINER
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), dh-virtualenv (>= 0.7), python3, python3-pyqt5
Standards-Version: 3.9.5

Package: MYPACKAGE
Architecture: any
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1), python3, ${misc:Pre-Depends}
Depends: ${python:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: My Description
```

Here's my rules file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
    dh $@ --with python-virtualenv

override_dh_virtualenv:
    dh_virtualenv --python /usr/bin/python3 --upgrade-pip --extra-index-url='MYINTERNALURL'
override_dh_shlibdeps:
    dh_shlibdeps --dpkg-shlibdeps-params=--ignore-missing-info
```

When I execute `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`, Everything works fine until `dpkg-shlibdeps`:

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libasound.so.2 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libQt53DExtras.so.5 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sceneparsers/libgltfsceneimport.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sceneparsers/../../lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libQt53DRender.so.5 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sceneparsers/libgltfsceneimport.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sceneparsers/../../lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libQt53DInput.so.5 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sceneparsers/libgltfsceneimport.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sceneparsers/../../lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libQt53DLogic.so.5 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sceneparsers/libgltfsceneimport.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sceneparsers/../../lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libQt53DCore.so.5 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sceneparsers/libgltfsceneimport.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sceneparsers/../../lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libQt5Gamepad.so.5 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sceneparsers/libgltfsceneimport.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sceneparsers/../../lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libQt5MultimediaGstTools.so.5 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/mediaservice/libgstcamerabin.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/mediaservice/../../lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libasound.so.2 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/mediaservice/libgstcamerabin.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/mediaservice/../../lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/mediaservice/libgstcamerabin.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/mediaservice/../../lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libpulse.so.0 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/mediaservice/libgstcamerabin.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/mediaservice/../../lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/audio/libqtmedia_pulse.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/audio/../../lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libpulse.so.0 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/audio/libqtmedia_pulse.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/audio/../../lib')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libicudata.so.56 needed by debian/sano-potentiostats-host/opt/venvs/sano-potentiostats-host/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libicuuc.so.56 (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/home/qt/icu_install/lib')
```

What I don't get is this:
yes, these libraries seem to be missing. No, they are not needed to run my application (for example Qt5 3D is definitely not needed, or Qt5 gamepad...)
So why can't I just build my debian package ignoring these missing libraries?
And what can I do to solve this? do I have to investigate libraries one by one and try to get the .so's needed? Some seem not so easy to get, for example: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt3D_Installation

Any help much appreciated

Comment: I've been installing a few packages to get these missing dependencies, but I'm still struggling to find some, like libQt5MultimediaGstTools.so.5 and libQt5Gamepad.so.5

Comment: Hey Kevin. I have quite similar issue. Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I have not. Have you?

Comment: Unfortunately No, we had to give up on this

Comment: Same here. I ended up having Ubuntu on an usb stick and have some clone operation to clone the needed app to a separate partition and a setup script for the Ubuntu part. Worked well

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you were looking for is [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize).

This utility searches the binary files you specify on the command line and gathers the corresponding libraries. It then repeats doing so for the library dependencies until all the dependencies are in a folder in your tree.

Then you simply include that tree in your Docker (`COPY ...`) and your binaries run as expected. The cool thing is that you get exactly what is required instead of a lot more libraries and files that are just fluff found in packages (i.e. documentation which will never be read from within a docker).